# When running the Django Server getting Bad Request or Path Error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a Django Project under which I have created an app named as `products`. I have put some piece of code in the `models.py` file of this `products` app i.e.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', default='bob.png')
    price = models.FloatField(help_text='in US Dollars $')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

After that I have registered the class in the `admin.py` file of the `products` app. The code for that is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)
```

After that I fired the commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`
`python manage.py runserver`

After running this last command I am getting the error mentioned in [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyIDE.png). After that I have changed the `DEBUG` mode to **False** but after that I am getting error mentioned in [error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyGn7.png). I have even changed the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` field value in the settings.py file to ['*'] or ['127.0.0.1'] but still I am getting the `Bad Request error`.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: did you try http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin?

Answer (score 0):

You actually get the error when accessing the page in the browser, which means the `runserver` command works fine. And you get the error because there's no index (`/`) route set.

If you want to access Django's admin interface, use http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/.

Comment: Yes I did try that @alv2017 but I am still getting the same issue.